# UnknownHostException when downloading gradle wrapper in docker conatiner

Tags: java, docker, jenkins, gradle

I have java gradle projects having different versions of java (8 and 11).

All these projects are being built on different CI pipelines but on the same pipeline server where the java home is pointed to java 8.

I'm writing a continuous integration pipeline on jenkins for a project written in java 11.

Normally this project won't be able to compile on the CI pipeline server as it is using the JAVA_HOME variable which is pointed to java 8.

So i decided to build this project inside a docker container.

I wrote a docker file

```
FROM gradle:jdk11
RUN mkdir /app
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN chmod 755 gradlew
RUN ./gradlew clean build

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom", "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005","-jar","build/libs/MyProject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

The build is failing and the following exception is being logged

```
Step 6/7 : RUN ./gradlew clean build 
 ---> Running in 635ea12aa9a4
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.0.1-bin.zip

[91mException in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: services.gradle.org
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:220)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:558)
    at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:182)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:474)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:569)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:341)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:362)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1248)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1187)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1081)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:1015)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1587)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1515)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:66)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:51)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:62)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:69)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
[0mThe command '/bin/sh -c ./gradlew clean build' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Gradle wrapper is not able to download the corresponding distribution 
I tried changing the distributionUrl to use http rather that https but it logged the same exception anyway

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.0.1-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

Do i need to change or add something in the dockerfile? or is it something else?

Comment: You should use the Gradle image, which you are doing. Except your command utilizes the local wrapper. Use the Docker image's Gradle instead (i.e., `gradle` instead of `./gradlew`).